# Time dependent Schrodinger equation through variation principle - questions about derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, schroedinger-equation, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I'm reading a text which discusses time dependent variation principle (Geometry of the Time-Dependent Variational Principle in Quantum Mechanics by Kramer and Saraceno), and there is some part of a derivation which I cannot understand. I'm trying to do a similar derivation in a slightly different context, so if anyone here could shed some light on what I don't understand, that would be really helpful.

This is the relevant part:

[image]
[image]

Up to the integration by parts I understand everything, so everything that happens up until then you can take as given. They then write "therefore, up to some total derivatives, we obtain...".

But I do not understand why this is what they obtain. When I plug in the integration by parts (and ignore the total derivatives, since they won't affect the solution), I get something slightly different:

[image]

Note that I know the origin for one difference - for my case I am taking $\langle\psi | \psi\rangle=1$, and so the term which depends on $\langle\delta\psi | \psi\rangle$ vanishes (and that makes sense, I'm fine with it). But the Hamiltonian term seems to be different than what they get and I am not sure why.

Moreover, I am not sure how they made the step that leads to equation $(2.3)$ (with this treatment of the bra and ket as independent variables). Does anyone understand how they did it?

By the way, just for completeness, this is the relevant Lagrangian:

[image]

If anything here needs further clarification, let me know.

Comment: Try to see if these questions are useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/357091/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/385345/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/579929/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/487935/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/623285/226902

Comment: @Quillo Thanks. I tried to look into them before posting, but they are not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's see.

1. The Lagrangian is
   $$ L~=~ \frac{\langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle}{2||\psi ||^2} ~+~ c.c.,\qquad ||\psi ||^2~\equiv~\langle \psi | \psi\rangle.  \tag{A}$$
   An infinitesimal variation is
   $$\begin{align} 
   \delta L~=~&\frac{\langle \delta \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle + \langle  \psi | i \partial_t -H |\delta \psi\rangle}{2||\psi ||^2} \cr
   &+ \langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle\delta \frac{1}{2||\psi ||^2} ~+~ c.c.\cr
   ~\stackrel{IBP}{\sim}~&\frac{\langle \delta \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle + \langle  \psi |- i \stackrel{\leftarrow}{\partial_t} -H |\delta \psi\rangle}{2||\psi ||^2} \cr
   &-\langle \psi | \delta \psi\rangle \partial_t \frac{i}{2||\psi ||^2} \cr
   & -\langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle  \frac{\langle \delta\psi | \psi\rangle+\langle \psi | \delta \psi\rangle }{2||\psi ||^4} ~+~ c.c.\cr
   ~=~&\frac{\langle \delta \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle}{||\psi ||^2} 
   + \langle \delta\psi | \psi\rangle \partial_t \frac{i}{2||\psi ||^2} \cr
   & -\langle\delta\psi |\psi\rangle \frac{\langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle + \overline{\langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle}}{2||\psi ||^4}  ~+~ c.c.
   \end{align}\tag{B}$$
   In the 2nd equality of eq. (B) we dropped a total time derivative term. In the 3rd equality of eq. (B) we strategically swopped terms with the $c.c.$ part, and we used that $H$ is self-adjoint.
2. We can treat $\langle \delta \psi |$ and $| \delta \psi \rangle$ as independent in eq. (B), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89002/2451) Phys.SE post. This leads to$^1$
   $$\begin{align} 
   0~\approx~&   ( i \partial_t -H )|\psi\rangle
   +  | \psi\rangle  ||\psi ||^2   \partial_t \frac{i}{2||\psi ||^2} \cr
   & -|  \psi\rangle  \frac{\langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle + \overline{\langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle}}{2||\psi ||^2}. 
   \end{align}\tag{C}$$
   Contracting with $\langle \psi |$ yields
   $$ 
   0~\approx~   \partial_t \frac{i}{2||\psi ||^2} 
    +  \frac{\langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle - \overline{\langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle}}{2||\psi ||^4}. 
   \tag{D}$$
   Eqs. (C) & (D) indeed imply the projected [TDSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) in Ref. 1
   $$ 
   0~\approx~   ( i \partial_t -H )|\psi\rangle 
       -|\psi\rangle  \frac{\langle \psi | i \partial_t -H |\psi\rangle}{||\psi ||^2}.\tag{2.3} 
   $$

References:

1. P. Kramer & M. Saraceno, *Geometry of the Time-Dependent Variational Principle in Quantum Mechanics,* Lecture Notes in Physics 140, 1981.

--

$^1$ The $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo [EL equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).