# How can we form Euler-Lagrange equations for Time-Independent Schrodinger Equations?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, schroedinger-equation, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

Is it possible to form a lagrangian of the TISE using the concept of Lagrange Multipliers? I am new to this topic so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "a lagrangian of the TISE"? Euler-Lagrange equations are equations for something evolving in time, but the time-**independent** Schrödinger equation does not evolve in time, that's its entire point.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/579929/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @ACuriousMind it is very much possible to find E-L equations that do not depend explicitly on time. The time dependence is built into the function $\psi$ as $\psi$ depends on time. Same goes for $\psi^{*}$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Finding  the stationary points of
$$
\chi[\psi, \psi^*]= \int \left\{\psi^*(-\nabla^2 \psi)+V(x)\right\}\psi\, dx
$$ subject to $\int |\psi|^2 dx=1$  leads to
the Euler-Lagrange equations
$$
-\nabla^2 \psi +V\psi=E\psi\\
-\nabla^2 \psi^* +V\psi^*=E\psi^*
$$
Here $E$ is the Lagrange multiplier enforcing the constraint and the equations are the Schroedinger equation and its conjugate.